# Getting distinct objects of a queryset from a reverse relation in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=189)

class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="messages")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I want to do here is that I want to get the queryset of distinct Customers ordered by the Message.created_at. My database is mysql.

I have tried the following.

```
qs = Customers.objects.all().order_by("-messages__created_at").distinct()
m = Messages.objects.all().values("customer").distinct().order_by("-created_at")
m = Messages.objects.all().order_by("-created_at").values("customer").distinct()
```

In the end , I used a set to accomplish this, but I think I might be missing something. My current solution:

```
customers = set(Interaction.objects.all().values_list("customer").distinct())
customer_list = list()
for c in customers:
    customer_list.append(c[0])
```

**EDIT**
Is it possible to get a list of customers ordered by according to their last message time but the queryset will also contain the last message value as another field?

Comment: There is a semantical problem: what if a user has written *multiple* `Message`s? This is actually where all these solutions get stuck.

Comment: Furthermore what about customers that have written no messages *at all*?

Comment: A user will have multiple messages. I want to get a list of customers who will be ordered according to their latest messages. If customer1 has last messaged at 5pm and customer2 has last messaged at 6pm on the same day, then the qs of customers will have [customer2, customer1]. 
edit: If the customer has no messages, then they will be at last or not shown at all. Anything will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment you want to order the customers based on their *latest* message. We can do so by *annotating* the `Customer`s and then sort on the annotation:

```
from dango.db.models import Max

Customer.objects.annotate(
    last_message=Max('messages__crated_at')
).order_by("-last_message")
```

A potential problem is what to do for `Customer`s that have written no message at all. In that case the `last_message` attribute will be `NULL` (`None`) in Python. We can specify this with `nulls_first` or `nulls_last` in the `.order_by` of an `F`-expression. For example:

```
from dango.db.models import F, Max

Customer.objects.annotate(
    last_message=Max('messages__crated_at')
).order_by(F('last_message').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

A nice bonus is that the `Customer` objects of *this queryset* will have an extra attribute: the `.last_message` attribute will specify what the last time was when the user has written a message.

You can also decide to filter them out, for example with:

```
from dango.db.models import F, Max

Customer.objects.filter(
    messages__isnull=False,
).annotate(
    last_message=Max('messages__crated_at')
).order_by('-last_message')
```